# Access elements of tuple in list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have a list of tuples, for example:

```
[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
```

Now I have to write function which sum up the first an second element of each tuple and create a list of these values.

For the example above it should be:

```
[3, 7, 11]
```

This should be done with use of list comprehension. It's not allowed to use functions like map, filter and contact.

Any ideas how I could access the elements of the tuple in the list?

Comment: Btw you mean `concat` not `contact`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
[ x + y | (x,y) <- yourlist]
```

The trick is representing the two elements in a tuple from your input list as `x` and `y` and then dealing with them as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do it without list comprehensions, using functions from the Prelude:

```
map (uncurry (+)) [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]

-- Result: [3, 7, 11]
```

How does this work?  Let's consider the types:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

As you may already know, in Haskell, the normal way of doing multi-argument functions is by **currying* them.  The type of `(+)` reflects this: conceptually it takes one argument and produces a function that then takes the "second" argument to produce the final result.

`uncurry` takes such a curried two-argument function and adapts it to work on a pair.  It's trivial to implement:

```
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
uncurry f (a, b) = f a b
```

Funnily enough, the `uncurry` function is curried, so its partial application `uncurry (+)` has type `Num a => (a, a) -> a`.  This would then be a function that takes a pair of numbers and adds them.

And `map` simply applies a function to every element of a list, collecting the individual results into a list.  Plug them all together and that's a solution.